# How dos ssh connects to an aws EC2 instance even though I didn't explicitly save the public key of the instance on the client?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-ec2, ssh, public-key-encryption

As I understand the way ssh works is that the two parties agree on a symmetric key for each session. This agreement is done by using the parties' corresponding public key, so it assumes that each party has access to the public key of the other entity. For example, this happens using the Diffie-Hellman key exchange algorithm.

However, when sshing to an AWS instance, my client doesn't seem to have access to the public key of the instance (in that I didn't explicitly save it on the client), so how is the key exchange part of the ssh process completed?

Answer (score 1):

When ssh client connects to the server, the server presents its own public key to the client.  If the client does not have the public key, it can prompt the user to establish the trust with the host. If the user accepts the prompt, the client uses the public of the server and might save it locally for future ssh connections. You can typically see that key in ~/.ssh/known_hosts